# How to make the stock "DigitalClock" randomly appear on screen in different location every minute

Tags: android, random, clock, appearance

absolute beginner (to android) here,

I've got a very simple android project in eclipse, Basically just a fullscreen activity with a digital clock placed inside a Linearlayout. I just want that clock to appear in a random postion of the screen every time the minute changes or every 30 seconds or whatever.

Now I'm not asking someone here to magic up some code that will make this work, I realize this is going to a lot of time and research (which I am doing!). Even if someone could point me in the right direction as where to look as nowhere seems to have what I need.

Answer (score 0):

A very general question. Lets see.

I believe your clock has co-ordinates `(x,y)` that represent center. Also there will be some range of values that it can take (depending on screen resolution?). Every 30 seconds generate two random numbers from that range and use it as new center.